# Simple 2D lighting in MonoGame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

So I have been looking for a way to implement SIMPLE 2D lighting into a top-down game I'm creating in MonoGame. I have searched far and wide, and have found few tutorials that help me little, if any. I simply wish to add a black overlay to my level, and then cut out the areas from the texture in which a light source would be. I am foreign to the concept of .FX files and converting them to be compatible with MonoGame. If there is some sort of way to have a "subtraction" blend mode, that would be perfect, if I only knew how to create/use it.